# How to disable password autocomplete or autofill in all browser types & versions

Tags: html, autocomplete, passwords

i have issue with autofill/ auto populate password in textbox. there are certain solution available over internet , those breaks with different browser types and versions.

i have tried below. 
- autocomplete = "off"
- autocomplete = "new-password"
- using jquery by injecting autocomplete tag.
- etc

can someone suggest me better solution that will work with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases, a browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values
>   even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. The trick to really
>   force the no-completion is to assign a random string to the attribute
>   like so :

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick code.

```html
<input name="foilautofill" style="display: none;" type="password" />
```

Your password is still saved into the browser, but when you load a page, password field will be blank.

Comment: HI i have found article on google. which is similar as your answer.. but it did covered more....  http://www.thehowtoarticles.com/2016/09/how-to-disable-password-autocomplete.html